# Qué quiere decir un archivo tipo: images.html~

Tags: formato

Tengo una carpeta en la que he intentado modificar el archivo images.html y de algún lado apareció una copia del mismo archivo con el símbolo ~ al final. Quisiera saber qué quiere decir este archivo y por qué cuando modifico el archivo original, sin el símbolo, los cambios no se ven reflejados en mi página web. Esto mismo me ha sucedido con varios archivos.

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de ser una copia de seguridad de una versión anterior de tu código HTML generada por tu editor, ¿con qué editor trabajas? ¿Bajo que sistema operativo?

Comment: Estoy trabajando en el editor de texto emacs, en linux